# OpenSSH U2F as second factor with fallback to Google Authenticator

Tags: linux, openssh, pam, 2-factor-authentication, fido-u2f

We use Google Authenticator for 2FA SSH logins. It's configured in `/etc/pam.d/sshd` as follows:

```
@include common-password
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so nullok
```

As you may know, [OpenSSH 8.2 comes with U2F keys support](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.2). We'd like to use U2F in the following manner:

1. If user authenticates with U2F-enabled key, let them in without asking for Google Authenticator code.
2. If user authenticates with a simple key, ask for Authenticator code.

How do I achieve that? U2F keys are of the specific type (note the `-SK` suffix):

```
$ ssh-keygen -l -f ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk.pub 
256 SHA256:8+ktnvXXshnIek7fEffbEQUhFvwZXOfahSHRagxcdbc pypt@NN (ECDSA-SK)
```

so maybe there's a way to configure PAM to allow in only specific key types?